# Default value in a FOSUserBundle form : data option do not work

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have modified directly a FOSUserForm (with no overriding) to try and assign a default value while building the form, I have added the

```
array('data'=>'default value')
```

such as:

```
namespace FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
private $class;

/**
 * @param string $class The User class name
 */
public function __construct($class)
{
    $this->class = $class;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username', null, array('data' => 'Default value','label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('email', 'email', array('data' => 'Default value','label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => $this->class,
        'intention'  => 'registration',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'fos_user_registration';
}
```

It doesn't work and I keep having a form validation message "Please enter a username"
what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the username as a hidden field instead of "null"? Or remove the username from the form completely and set it manually before the entity is persisted in the database.  I don't recommend the second option unless you have performed a check to make sure the username is unique before persisting it to the database.

Edit:

Out of curiousity, why are you modifying a vendor class directly?

Edit 2:

The default validation for the username field should probably not be removed (and if you do, make sure it is still a unique field in the database (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html).

If you want to set a default username value, instead of setting the data option in the form, create a custom RegistrationFormHandler that overrides the default createUser method:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Handler;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Handler\RegistrationFormHandler as BaseHandler;

class RegistrationFormHandler extends BaseHandler
{
    /**
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    protected function createUser()
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setUsername('customusername');

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Instructions on overriding this handler can be found here (towards the bottom): 
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

It's pretty simple, should only take a minute to implement. Additionally, creating the custom formhandler will also prevent any changes you've made in the vendor classes from being lost when you update your vendors via composer.

Edit 3:

DependencyInjection\EtienneUserExtension.php:

```
<?php

namespace Etienne\UserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

//if using xml
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;

//if using yaml
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class EtienneUserExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        //if using XML
        $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        //or if using yaml services
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'etienne_user';
    }
}
```

services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">


<services>
    <service id="acme_user.form.handler.registration" class="Acme\UserBundle\Form\RegHandler" scope="request" public="false">
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.registration.form" />
        <argument type="service" id="request" />
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager" />
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.mailer" />
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.util.token_generator" />
    </service>
</services>

</container>
```

Comment: well thanx for your msg...i am not trying to remove username...i am trying to remove username validation messages that comes prematurely when i open the form view

Comment: why modifying vendor class directly ? because it is urgent and i did not manage to override the form

Comment: thanx a lot for your help ...here is what i get  InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "etienne_user.form.handler.registration" does not exist.

Comment: Ensure that you have the new registration handler service id defined in your services.xml.  The definition can basically be copied and pasted from the docs (see link in post).. Just change service ID and class.

Comment: @ihave created the Etienne/UserBundle/Form/Handler/RegistrationFormHandler as yours then services.yml in Resources/config and modified the app/config....

Comment: Make sure services.xml is being loaded in DependencyInjection\EtienneUserExtension.php ($loader->load('services.xml');) .. Or if you're using YML services, use YamlFileLoader

Comment: ooo i dont have any EtienneUserExtension.php

Comment: what shall i put in there?

Comment: See my edit.. That should do it.  In the future, if you're not already doing so, create new bundles via the command line "php app/console generate:bundle"  this will automatically create the dependency injection for you.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader as XmlFileLoader because the name is already in use in /var/www/projet_etienne_auth/src/Etienne/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/EtienneUserExtension.php on line 11

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my use statements.  Replace the second XmlFileLoader use with YamlFileLoader (see the edit now)

Comment: InvalidArgumentException: [ERROR 64] XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document (in n/a - line 2, column 6)

Comment: This conversation is getting too long for stackoverflow's rules.  Ensure your services.xml contains the correct node setup, does not contain spaces before the <?xml tag, and has a <container, <services, and then <service node setup.  Consider reading more of the symfony documentation.  See my last edit for the services.xml example.

Comment: i am very grateful for all that time spent for me ;)

Comment: the overriding work now which is great and being very "teachingful" altough the     $user->setUsername('customusername'); did not seem to have put a default value

Comment: I can't know what's going on on your end.  I tested this code on my end and it was working fine.  Try updating your FOSUserBundle back to its original state via composer and see if that helps.